# Among several given ways to test a string against two possible values using strcmp, is one of them an obvious choice?

Tags: c, performance, if-statement, boolean-logic, strcmp

I wish to test a string against "y" and "yes" and if it is either, do something. (Well, not really but this is the equivalent of the real code.) The following three ways of doing the test in C are logically equivalent. I am curious how more experienced programmers would choose among these possibilities and why.

```
if ( strcmp(mystring,"y")==0 || strcmp(mystring,"yes")==0 ) { something(); }

if ( !strcmp(mystring,"y") || !strcmp(mystring,"yes") ) { something(); }

if ( !(strcmp(mystring,"y") && strcmp(mystring,"yes")) ) { something(); }
```

Each of these has pros and cons. I am also aware that it's best to write code that is easiest to read and maintain. What's unclear to me is whether most C programmers would consider the second as easy or easier to read than the first. If so, then its shorter length makes it the best choice of the three. (The third seems extra confusing to read so despite its lower number of max operations, doesn't seem the best choice.)

Maybe something I didn't even consider is best like

```
if ( strcmp(mystring,"y") && strcmp(mystring,"yes") ) {} else { something(); }
```

Comment: What about checking only the first char against "y" ?

Comment: "Each of these has pros and cons" - elaborating on what *you* think those are may very well answer your own question, at least partially.

Comment: No, I want the code to run on only exactly "y" or "yes" and something like "yep" not to run it.

Comment: This has nothing to do with performance

Comment: @ Matt McNabb. My question is more about coding style than performance but this question absolutely could have something to do with performance. It'd be real easy to imagine sticking this test in a deeply nested for loop and having functions generate one string and another generating the second. Efficiencly would certainly become an issue then so your comment is counterproductive unless you wish to elaborate.

Comment: The compiler will generate the fastest assembly, most likely the same for all of your cases. That's what compilers do, they aren't just a one-to-one translation of the symbols you put in your .c file .

Comment: @Matt McNabb. Except you say "most likely" which means it may not. It becomes extra uncertain if one distributes non-optimized code so that customers can have debug symbols and would require digging into the compiler's output to know for sure. And it rarely hurts to give the compiler hints on a good way to optimize.

Comment: You wouldn't worry about micro-optimization in a debug version, and it is harmful to give the compiler hints if your hints would make the performance worse (which you have no idea about but the compiler does have every idea about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there are known performance issues with one approach vs another, always prefer the approach that is easier to read and understand.

Given your three choices, I would most definitely go with:

```
if ( strcmp(mystring,"y")==0 || strcmp(mystring,"yes")==0 ) { something(); }
```

**Update**

You can define a macro that will help make it more straight forward and easy to read.

```
#define STRING_EQUAL(A, B) (strcmp((A), (B)) == 0)

if ( STRING_EQUAL(mystring,"y") || STRING_EQUAL(mystring,"yes") ) { something(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very subjective.

I prefer the **first** because it is simple to understand: `strcmp()==0` means *equivalent* (this is a no-brainer for anyone with any exposition to assembler, where you test for equality of two registers by subtracting them and comparing the result to 0--at least that's what the CPU does). The other alternative using `!strcmp()` has the logic backwards and `!(strcmp() && strcmp())` is plain obfuscation. All IMHO. I *will* catch some flak for this.

Comment: This question is entirely opinion based, but I agree the first option is far and away the 'correct' one.

Comment: Technically, the question is not subjective because of the word "obvious". If you believe there's not an obvious choice, then your answer is "no".

Comment: `!(strcmp() && strcmp())` uses 2 Boolean operations, and if the first `strcmp` returns 0, then only the NOT is applied. Otherwise, the AND and the NOT are both applied in that order. `!strcmp() || !strcmp()` uses 3 Boolean operations, and if the first `strcmp` returns nonzero, then only the first NOT is applied. Otherwise, the first NOT, AND, and last NOT are applied. A decent optimizing compiler will recognize this Boolean Algebra and optimize it to the 2-op version, derived via De Morgan's laws, assuming it would be more efficient on that machine, but it isn't one's job to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use macros and make it like natural language. I would prefer the following approach. The maintenance and the readability are easier.

`#define IS_THE_ANS_YES(A) (!strcmp((A),"yes") | !strcmp((A),"y")) 
...
if (IS_THE_ANS_YES(mystring)) { something(); }`